# Sybase/SAP ASE jConnect with roman8 character encoding

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase, sap-ase

Sybase 16 configured with hp-roman8 encoding (do not ask) does not connect without specifying CHARSET= on the connection string, like this:

`jdbc:sybase:Tds:10.0.0.X:5000/db_name?CHARSET=iso_1&ENCRYPT_PASSWORD=true`

This is because java does not support hp-roman8. But that changes when I include the [JCharset](https://www.freeutils.net/source/jcharset/) package.

After including it (JCharset) jConnect connects without the CHARSET= parameter, but Strings get messed up anyways.

SyBooks Online [recommends setting](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_12.5.2.aserbhp/html/aserbhp/aserbhp80.htm) `CHARSET` to `iso_1`, but that does not work either.

The JCharset solution seemed interesting, any ideas why it did not work?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `CHARSET_CONVERTER_CLASS=com.sybase.jdbc4.charset.TruncationConverter` works, but it does not seem 100% safe.